# Android mock location provider sample app is not working

Tags: android, mock-location

I am trying to build a simple Android mock location provide (Android 7.0). I am getting a `Java.Lang.SecurityException` on ... not allowed to perform **MockLocationException**. I have `android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` in manifest file. I have also tried the same with `Xamarin` and got the same error.

```
Location location = new Location(LocationManager.GpsProvider);

location.Latitude = 20.0;
location.Longitude = 20.0;
location.Accuracy = 0;
location.Time = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
location.ElapsedRealtimeNanos = 100;
location.Speed = 0.0f;
location.Altitude = 1.0;
location.Bearing = 0.0f;

LocationManager locationManager = GetSystemService(LocationService) as 
LocationManager;

locationManager.AddTestProvider(LocationManager.GpsProvider, false, 
       false, false, false, false, false, false, Power.Low, 
Android.Hardware.SensorStatus.AccuracyHigh);
// getting exception on the above line

locationManager.SetTestProviderLocation(LocationManager.GpsProvider, 
           location);
locationManager.SetTestProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GpsProvider, true);
```

Comment: pls indicate if this solved the problem...

Comment: The problem I see is, I am not able to select my app as the mock location provider (In Android setting). I could see my app name in the list of Mock location providers though. But there are some other applications as well in the list and they are selectable as well.

Comment: scroll through this...https://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-6/help/select-mock-location-app-stuck-t3423268

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable **Allow mock locations** within the **Settings** - **Developer options** settings on your device, and add the ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION permission within your manifest. This will enable you to send mock locations to your app