# Is it possible to set arbitrary device location programmatically, per UI test

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator, firebase-test-lab

I was wondering if there is any legitimate way of setting Espresso-based UI test location programmatically (please assume there is no adb access to device, there is no way to enable mock location from device settings). I don't think it's possible but posting the question in case I missed something.

PS.: I am using FusedLocationProvider if that matters.

Comment: You will need to mock the location. This might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/how-to-mock-location-on-device

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Test Lab supports mocked locations.
You'll probably need to install a location provider from your test package, e.g.
[Android mock location provider sample app is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55721716/android-mock-location-provider-sample-app-is-not-working)

See also [How to mock location on device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2531317/how-to-mock-location-on-device)

Comment: Thnx. First link says "You need to enable Allow mock locations within the Settings - Developer options" - this is not an option to me. 2nd link has various answers but imo it all ends up with "go to dev settings on the device".

Comment: Add `android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION` to debug manifest